# Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, segue

I keep getting the error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setPhotoCellName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

when I enter my prepare for segue call. Currently I have

> TabBarController->NavigationController->TableViewController->TableViewController->ViewController

with a UI image on it.

The problem occurs when I try to segue from the second TableView controller to the ViewController. I have the segue setup from the Prototype Cell to the actual ViewController. It enters the segue and crashes. I am trying to pass an `NSArray` property over to the `viewController` to be able to use a URL in it and display the `UIImage`. PhotoInPlace contains the array that Im trying to pass. Here is the code.

myTableViewControllerPhotoLocation.m Code

```
#import "myTableViewControllerPhotoLocation.h"
#import "FlickrImageViewController.h"

@interface myTableViewControllerPhotoLocation ()
@end

@implementation myTableViewControllerPhotoLocation
@synthesize photoInPlace = _photoInPlace; //Contains NSArray to pass


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Photo Display"]){
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSLog(@" Dicitonary = %@", [self.photoInPlace objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); //Returns the picked cell
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.photoInPlace class]); //returns NSArray
        NSLog(@"%@", [self photoInPlace]); //Returns the array

        [segue.destinationViewController setPhotoCellName:[self.photoInPlace objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
        //Crashes HERE!
    }
}
```

FlickrImageViewController.h Code

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* photoCellName;
```

FlickrImageViewController.m Code

```
#import "FlickrImageViewController.h"

@interface FlickrImageViewController ()
@end

@implementation FlickrImageViewController
@synthesize photoCellName = _photoCellName; //property declared in header


-(void) setPhotoCellName:(NSArray *)photoCellName{
    if(!_photoCellName)
        _photoCellName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:photoCellName];
    else {
        _photoCellName = photoCellName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the this style of code to pass an Array in the prior TVC I dont know why its crashing on this one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You believe that your destination is an object from the `FlickrImageViewController` but the app doesn't.  Look at the class you have assigned that controller in your storyboard; according to the error, it's a bare `UIViewController`.

Comment: so you have to assign the view in storyboard the controllers class?

Comment: Not the view, the view controller.  When it gets loaded from the storyboard, the runtime has to know which type of object to create.

Comment: I changed the class of the ViewController to the FlickrImageViewController but now i get a new error, [NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray

Comment: I fixed the second problem it was an error in my code writing I changed it to NSDictionary and it works thanks for the help! It's annoying how such a little and simple problem took me forever to figure out! thanks again!

Comment: This saved me from tearing my hair out & wasting another 20 mins debugging with NSLog. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you've accidentally got a plain vanilla UIViewController rather than a FlickrImageViewController. Maybe you forgot to assign the controller's class?