# "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" getting crash when pushing view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, viewcontroller

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', > reason: '-[UIViewController setDicSelectListItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10981be30'

I tried comment parameter passing. also tried provide main storyboard.

Below is the code where app getting crash

```
   BilingInfoVC *vc = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BilingInfoVC"];
    vc.dicSelectListItem=_dicSelectListItem;
    vc.serviceType=_serviceType;
    vc.arrSelect_Addons = [arrTemp mutableCopy];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I want to pass parameters with instantiate view controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803579/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

Is vc really of class 'BilingInfoVC'? If you didn't assign it correctly in IB it's a standard view controller.

You may check it with

```
NSLog(@"Class: %@", [vc className]);
```

As second line right after instantination of vc.

Did you set the identifier correctly? A capital letter can make a difference!